# How to migrate javascript file into typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need some help/suggestion on how can I able to migrate javascript file into typescript.
I am very early beginner on typescript.
I have gone through many tuorials as well https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html but not able to do so .

Any help/suggestion would be very helpful.

//eaxmple code

```
(function() {

    "use strict";
  
    var CONSTANTS = {
      PROTOCOL_SECURE : "https://",
      PROTOCOL : "http://"
    };

  
  
    var constantNew = window.constantNew = function() {};

  constantNew.prototype.init = function(params) {
      this.lobby = params.lobby;
      this.bSecure = !!params.bSecure;
    };

    constantNew.prototype.getPMAInfo = function() {
      var url = (this.bSecure? CONSTANTS.PROTOCOL_SECURE:DEMETER_CONSTANTS.PROTOCOL)
      +this.lobby
      +CONSTANTS.URL_GETPMAINFO_PATH;

      return Promise.resolve({baseUrl:url})
        .then(callDemeter)                       // just a call to demeter to get PMA Info
        .then(decoratePmaData)                    // a small decorator
        .catch(checkGeneralFailure("getPMAInfo"));// final error handler
    };

    constantNew.prototype.hangoutAuthenticate = function(args) {
  
      var baseUrl = (this.bSecure? DEMETER_CONSTANTS.PROTOCOL_SECURE:DEMETER_CONSTANTS.PROTOCOL)
      +this.lobby
      +DEMETER_CONSTANTS.URL_HANGOUT_AUTHENTICATE;
  
      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(requestChallengeFn(baseUrl))  // request challenge (higher order function to get the workflow function)     
        .then(authenticatePartialApplication(baseUrl, args.account, args.password, args.bValidateByConfCode)) // try first first auth round or fail
        .then(decorateHangoutAuthResult)    // decorate result to return
        .catch(checkGeneralFailure("hangoutAuthenticate")); // final error handler
        
      function decorateHangoutAuthResult(authResult) {
        return {
            strWebroom: authResult.webroom[0].webroomcode,
            strWebroomResource: authResult.webroom[0].resource,
            strDemeterAuthToken: authResult.AUTHTOKEN,
            strAudioConfCode: authResult.webroom[0].audioconferencecode
          };
      }
    };
  
  }());
```

Comment: 1. Change file name from `foo.js` to `foo.ts`. 2. Compile. 3. Fix errors reported, or come back here with concrete examples of errors you don't quite understand or know how to fix.

Comment: I have did most of them but still some erros reported here. 
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: DemeterDAO is not defined

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way of doing it unfortunately (i.e., via a script or some utility). Typescript provides the following guide to get you running there: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

That being the case, it might be better to start over. There's several options such as the Typescript Node Starter project in Github: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter